# Problems with queryBuilder greenDAO

Tags: java, greendao

I am using latest version of GreenDAO... I am missing something on using the data from the DB.

I need to prevent the creation of records that have the same PROFILE_NUMBER.  Currently during testing I have inserted 1 record with the PROFILE_NUMBER of 1.

I need someone to show me an example of how to obtain the actual value of the field from the db.

I am using this

```
SvecPoleDao svecPoleDao = daoSession.getSvecPoleDao();
List poles = svecPoleDao.queryBuilder().where(SvecPoleDao.Properties.Profile_number.eq(1)).list();
```

and it obtains something... this.

> [com.example.bobby.poleattachmenttest2_workingdatabase.db.SvecPole@bfe830c3.2]

Is this serialized?  The actual value I am looking for here is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.You'll need to use listlazy() instead of list().

```
List<SvecPole> poles = svecPoleDao.queryBuilder().where(SvecPoleDao.Properties.Profile_number.eq(1)).listLazy();
```